# how to give an error that the record cannot be deleted because it has a connection with the database using try/except

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am new to python and there is  problem, I need the system should display a message that it is impossible to delete the record, since it has connections in the database. how to do it right?
my code:

```
 @permission_required ('orauth.group_delete', raise_exception = True)
def group_delete (request, pk):
     group = get_object_or_404 (Group, pk = pk)

     if request.method == 'POST':
         group.delete ()
         return redirect ('orauth: group_list')

     return render (
         request,
         'common / confirm_delete.html',
         {
             'title': _ ('Deleting a role'),
             'object': group,
         },
     )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CMIW, Django has argument on_delete for model like Foreign key. You can choose whatever which suitable for you. you can read this [on_delete django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete)